# Using functools.partial within class structure, "name 'self' is not defined"

Tags: python, pandas, functools

Below is a significantly simplified version on my code. After the `__init__()` there are several functions.

I am trying to use `functools.partial` to create different versions of a basic `comparison` function, which references a function created earlier in the class, `calculation`. One version of this comparison function might be the `grade_comparison` seen below.

```
class Analysis(mybaseclass):

    def __init__(self, year, cycle):
....

    def calculation(self, subject):
        print subject

    def comparison(subject, **kwargs):
        self.calculation(subject)

    grade_comparison = functools.partial(comparison, infoList1 = ['A', 'B'])
```

When I run my code, there is an error, `NameError: global name 'self' is not defined`. I have tried adding `self` in many combinations that seemed logical - one example below.

```
self.grade_comparison = functools.partial(comparison, self, infoList1 = ['A', 'B'])
```

This change resulted in this error, `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`
When I add self to the comparison function (see below):

```
def comparison(self, subject, **kwargs):
        self.calculation(subject)
```

I get this error, `TypeError: comparison() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`. Please let me know if you need more context! As mentioned, this is the barebones of the code.

Comment: Hint: Look at `comparison` and its parameter list. Is there a `self`?

Comment: `functools.partial` doesn't support the descriptor protocol, so you can't use `partial` objects as methods like that anyway.

Comment: Could you clarify please? Why can't partial objects be used in this case?

Comment: @skrrgwasme: You can set `self.something = partial(self.otherthing, args)` in `__init__`, but you can't set it at class level, so `Analysis.grade_comparison` can't be a `partial` object. Setting it at instance level is kind of a mess, since introspection and reflection for that gets weird and overriding it doesn't work.

Comment: @user2357112 Ah, I see now. I misread her code. I somehow missed that she was assigning a partial *as* class method, and not using partial outside of the class *on* a class method. My mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want without `partial`:

```
class Analysis(object):

    def calculation(self, subject):
        print subject

    def comparison(self, subject, **kwargs):
        self.calculation(subject)

    def grade_comparison(self, subject):
        return self.comparison(subject, infoList1=['A', 'B'])
```

Comment: great example of how sometimes the simpler approach is the better one. i was thinking we should use decorators...